# Adjust for one factor in time series analysis

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, cross-section, adjustment

I would like to analyze whether blood pressure is higher in winter than in summer through time series analysis: in particular, I would like to use repeated/pooled cross-sectional time series analysis in my sample.

I want to know: I suspect that blood pressure could increase together with aging in my sample, so, how can I take into account it? For example, to address the issue that blood pressure could be seasonal only because age is.

(I use R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear are you collecting repeated measures on the same individuals? If so you could create a variable for each season (let's say you measured BP four times a season). Now let's say you had 25 subjects measured 4x a season, which would give you 400 observations.

Now this may or may not be exactly your situation but let's roll with it. You would maybe have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
> head(lv1)
    ID season   BP.sys
4    1   fall 116.8071
104  1   fall 120.3489
204  1   fall 121.5491
304  1   fall 125.6599
2    1 spring 124.6406
102  1 spring 124.7724
> tail(lv1)
    ID season   BP.sys
299 25 summer 126.1880
399 25 summer 126.1933
97  25 winter 142.7422
197 25 winter 146.6256
297 25 winter 142.8389
397 25 winter 148.9565
```

Okay, so now what can you do to see if there is an effect of season on BP? Well one option would be just to run a mixed effects model on it, perhaps allowing the effect of season to vary across individuals (you could add age as a covariate if you had the data). I tend to use the `lme4` package for these sorts of models.

```
library(lme4)
> fit<-lmer(BP.sys~1+season+(1+season|ID), data=lv1)
> summary(fit)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: BP.sys ~ 1 + season + (1 + season | ID)
   Data: lv1

REML criterion at convergence: 2544.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9006 -0.5680 -0.0226  0.6016  3.1650 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 ID       (Intercept)  181.150  13.459                    
          seasonspring   7.069   2.659   -0.48            
          seasonsummer   2.537   1.593    0.36  0.64      
          seasonwinter   1.494   1.222    0.44  0.58  1.00
 Residual               25.244   5.024                    
Number of obs: 400, groups:  ID, 25

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  125.7155     2.7383   45.91
seasonspring   2.1538     0.8875    2.43
seasonsummer  -5.3182     0.7787   -6.83
seasonwinter  10.1394     0.7514   13.49

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) ssnspr ssnsmm
seasonsprng -0.386              
seasonsummr  0.028  0.523       
seasonwintr  0.018  0.491  0.564
```

You can run the same model with the `lmerTest` package loaded to get significance tests for your coefficients. Note that it will automatically assign a reference category alphabetically, meaning the model estimates are all in reference to mean BP in the fall (which is the intercept in this model).

Hope that helps.

Comment: You put me on the right track: now it is just a matter of studying. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck!